# SELECT SUM(1) FROM ( SELECT '0' as R FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT '1' as R FROM dual )

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Why the following query giving value `2` instead of my expectation `1`?

```
SELECT SUM(1) FROM (
SELECT  '0' as R FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT  '1' as R FROM dual
)
```

But this query satisfying the expectation?

```
SELECT SUM(R) FROM (
SELECT  '0' as R FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT  '1' as R FROM dual
)
```

Comment: Please use a meaningful title

Comment: If the second query satisfies your expectation, then Oracle taught you to have the wrong expectation. You should EXPECT the second query to throw an error, because you are adding strings. Unfortunately Oracle has the bad habit of "reading your mind" and converting the strings to numbers, without warning. It will serve you very well to unlearn such habits.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first query you're summing 1 for each occurrence of any row in the selection, yet for query 1 you're summing whatever the value of 'R' is for each row in the selection.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is summing 1 for each record exists in the inner query. That is because you summed by a constant value : `SUM(1)` which will basically return the same result as `COUNT(*)/COUNT(1)` .

The second query is summing the values of `R` columns -> `0` and `1` which is equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

`SUM(1)` in the first query is equivalent to `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

because it adds `1` to the total for each row of the `FROM` table, regardless of the content of that row.

The second query pays attention to the value of `R`, so it adds `1` to `0`, and arrives at zero.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `SELECT 1` you are extracting the hardcoded value 1 and not, as you likely expected, the first column; your query is

```
SQL> SELECT 1
  2    FROM (SELECT '0' AS R FROM DUAL
  3          UNION
  4          SELECT '1' AS R FROM DUAL
  5         );

         1
----------
         1
         1
```

that is two rows containing 1; the `SUM` of these rows gives 2:

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(1)
  2    FROM (SELECT '0' AS R FROM DUAL
  3          UNION
  4          SELECT '1' AS R FROM DUAL
  5         );

    SUM(1)
----------
         2
```

For example, you can try

```
SQL> select 100
  2  from ( select 1 from dual);

       100
----------
       100
```

this clarifies that `select 100` does not look for the 100th column of the internal query, but simply gives the value 100.

In the following query you are extracting a variable value in `R` ( I edited the strings into numbers); in your query you have two rows like the following, where `R` is 0 in a row and 1 in the other one:

```
SQL> SELECT R
  2    FROM (SELECT 0 AS R FROM DUAL
  3          UNION
  4          SELECT 1 AS R FROM DUAL
  5         );

         R
----------
         0
         1
```

The SUM of these two values is `0 + 1 = 1`:

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(R)
  2    FROM (SELECT 0 AS R FROM DUAL
  3          UNION
  4          SELECT 1 AS R FROM DUAL
  5         );

    SUM(R)
----------
         1

SQL>
```